# Changing server time

Tags: mongodb

We have a daily invoicing procedure in the production server, which takes about 4 hours.

We are deploying a QA environment with mongo (3 replicas in the same machine), and our goal is to run this procedure with today's info, change enviroment's date to tomorrow, run the procedure, change the date to the date after tomorrow, run the procedure... and so on. This way, we get a week in two days.
We change the time using

```
sudo timedatectl set-time ${TIME}
```

There is no problem when we change "jump" one day or one month, but if we jump 6 months or more, mongo stops working and connection to 27017 is not LISTENING:

```
netstat -nap | grep mongo
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM                   4107509  -                    /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     32418    -                    /tmp/mongodb-27012.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     32393    -                    /tmp/mongodb-27011.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24202    -                    /tmp/mongodb-20000.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     33524    -                    /tmp/mongodb-27023.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     29140    -                    /tmp/mongodb-20002.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26360    -                    /tmp/mongodb-20001.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34090    -                    /tmp/mongodb-27013.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34093    -                    /tmp/mongodb-27021.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30073    -                    /tmp/mongodb-27022.sock
```

We have restarted the processes, manually remove the socket, reboot the machine... Nothing works.

Comment: It looks weird to hear changing system date for running a procedure!!

Comment: Do the mongod logs say why it stopped?

Comment: Changing the system time can have a lot of unintended side effects.  One example is if you forward the clock beyond the expiration date of the certificates, SSL/TLS will stop working